# Autocomplete item selection in Alloy UI

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, liferay, alloy-ui

I am working with Alloy UI auto-complete plugin that comes with Liferay. My auto complete part is working completely fine.

Now, what I want to do is that I want to capture the data which is selected from the auto complete auto suggest, and do the operation.

Let say, if I write `ry` in auto complete and then list comes up like this :

```
ryan
rynda
ryab
```

Now, if I click on any item or select via keyboard arrow key and press enter, it gets copied to autocomplete source input box. But I want is that I want to return back and do nothing when user selects a particular one item lets say `ryab`.

I found the event

```
autocomplete.on('itemSelect',function(event) {
};
```

which is fired when I select any item, but I don't know how to get the object which is selected and how to return false/do nothing by comparing the object.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
var expandit = false;

autocomplete.on('itemSelect', function(event) {
    var currentValue = autocomplete.inputNode.get('value');
    //do comparison logic with currentValue here, and eventually set input node value to empty string
    if (currentValue == 'foo') {
        expandit = true;
        autocomplete.inputNode.set('value', '');
        // stop event propagation
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }
});

autocomplete.on('containerCollapse', function(event) {
    //reopen the menu in case of "do nothing" selection
    if (expandit) {
        autocomplete._sendQuery(autocomplete.inputNode.get('value') + '*');
        expandit = false;
    }
});
```

Alloy UI [Reference API](http://alloyui.com/deploy/api/AutoComplete.html) and [Source Code](http://alloyui.com/deploy/api/aui-autocomplete-debug.js.html) for the `Autocomplete` widget have been useful.

---

To programmatically show the menu you can use:

```
autocomplete._sendQuery(autocomplete.inputNode.get('value') + '*');
```

Comment: Thanks! its working, right now, the menu disappears (suggestion list) if i click any of them, is it possible to show menu when I click "do nothing" item?

Comment: I got this point but what i want is that when I click the result for which I have done "do nothing", the result disappers, I want to show the result as it is, is that possible?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What exactly is your desired behavior when the user click a "do nothing" item?

Comment: As soon as you click any result from the suggested list of items, the result disappears. So, what I want is that when user will click on the item from the list, I dont want to get that suggested list to disapper, rather react like nothing has happened. So that user can go ahead and select the other text which is available for searching. Make sense?